# Insert link into a Pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination

I have made a pagination where user can insert value and press go. So I want to put a link in every value. For example
my website links are ..

```
www.website./page/1
www.website./page/2

www.website./page/3...
```

And so on
So if the user typed 3 into the pagination and pressed go I want to redirect the website to 
www.website./page/3 page 
So thats the whole point.

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: In `click` event redirect user to that page?

Comment: If the Pagination value is 3 I want to redirect to the 3rd page of my website as my website's pages are also 1 2 3

Comment: If the user typed 3 I want to redirect to 3rd page of the website as my website's sub pages are also named as page/1 page/2

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="href" />
<button onclick="location.href='www.website.com/page/' + document.getElementById('href').value">Go!</button>
```

Improve your expressions ffs